# Issue with eclipse juno for c,c++ in windows

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-juno

I am using MinGW for running c programs in eclipse juno in windows. My programs runs fine most of the times. But sometimes even though i dont have any errors in project, I get an error saying "There are errors in the project, do you want to continue". The problem gets resolved when I restart the eclipse and clean and build the project.

How can I resolve this issue. Pls help

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Make shure you have ...

- no missing includes
- set proper C / C++ standard (if required)
- Current Eclipse Version (maybe yours doesn't support current C / C++ standard)
- no marker in error/warning view
- no old compiled files in your output dir (use `clean` command)